# How to make text between parentheses bold using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I want to bold text between parentheses using jQuery / JavaScript. i.e.

```
"what is your Age (in Year)."
```

Text between parentheses should be bold using jQuery or JavaScript. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you've already tried. It's unlikely people are going to write code for you from scratch. You could probably scan text with JQuery and then match text in brackets using a regex and then wrap the inner text in a <span> styled to make the text bold.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please try with JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex, you can select text between parentheses and wrap it with `<b>` tag to showing bold.

```js
$("#str").html(function(i, h){
    return h.replace(/\(([^\)]+)\)/, "(<b>$1</b>)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="str">what is your Age (in Year)</div>
```

Comment: thank Mohammad its work !!! could you please tell me how to color and bold text togather between round bracket...

Comment: @NoumanSaeed Use `.find("b").css("color", "red")` after `.html()` to changing color of bold element. Check http://jsfiddle.net/mq94d6Lu/

Comment: Please add with example i m new in Jquery...as you mention above in Age example

Comment: @NoumanSaeed Look at my last comment carefully, I added example in jsfiddle

Comment: i want to bold text between ( ), and bold and color text between []

Comment: Dear Mohammad, your above code is not working with double bracket i.e... - What is your age (Year) (Month) it only highlight year not month

Comment: @NoumanSaeed So add `g` at end of first parameter of `.replace()` to work for global match. Regex should be `/\(([^\)]+)\)/g`

Comment: i want to bold text between ( ), and bold and color text between [] , thanks in advance

Comment: @NoumanSaeed You should search for your needs and try for it however its simple, check http://jsfiddle.net/mq94d6Lu/1/